# What and how does Darth Vader see?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

Are there any sources that talk about  about Darth Vader's visual acuity?

His life-supporting armour is quite advanced but does it provide any useful augmentation to his visual abilities?

Comment: Remember Geordi from Star Trek?

Comment: Is there anyone on this site who thinks that my question doesn't need to be edited? Edit on edit of edit...

Comment: What and how does Darth Vader see?  Stuff and very well, thank you.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The novel *Allegiance* establishes that Darth Vader's vision is, in several ways, actually **worse** than a normal human's. Mara Jade describes his visual interface as "having both the benefits and drawbacks of that technology." He is depicted as taking longer than a normal human to adjust to changes in ambient light; in other words, his vision blanks out if someone switches the lights on or off, just as would be the case with modern night-vision goggles.

Mara also acknowledges that this would not be the case with more modern visual interfaces; Vader's General Grievous-type interface is old, and not up to the standard of modern devices. You see a similar issue with the differences between Anakin Skywalker's artificial hand and his son Luke's. The design was meant to preserve his life, not to preserve it comfortably; in *Shadows of the Empire*, Vader himself mentions that even the act of breathing is extremely painful.

I do not know of any other sources on Vader's visual abilities. I would assume that, unlike a stormtrooper or Mandalorian combat helmet, Vader's helmet does not allow him a full 360 degree view of his surroundings, merely because that ability is never mentioned in any sources on Vader, whereas it is mentioned in multiple sources about Boba Fett and stormtroopers. Similarly, infrared and ultraviolet spectrum vision is never mentioned. For all intents and purposes, it seems that Vader has a fairly slapped-together system, which cannot be upgraded without killing him.

Comment: There's a brief shot from Vader's point-of-view at the end of Episode 3, as the mask is lowered onto his face. He seems to have a head-up display to show text information (presumably status indicators for his suit), but a rather restricted field of vision.

Comment: For what it's worth, I assume Vader's mastery of the Force would more than compensate for any limitations in his visual systems.

Comment: Yes this is very much in keeping with the idea of the force [being able to compensate for impaired vision](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13126/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-blast-shield-helmet).

Comment: @Blazemonger:
Although, on the flip side, some of the books imply that Darth Vader's cybernetic enhancements make use of the force more difficult, whether it's a loss of Essence or problems with routing the power through mechanical components (sometimes cited as the reason Vader never uses Force Lightning).

Comment: So let me get this straight: they can travel at lightspeed and make sentient robots, but their night vision tech is worse than ours?

Comment: @Gaius, maybe a case of [The Road Not Taken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Road_Not_Taken_(short_story)) situation?

Comment: @Gaius Advancement in one area does not imply advancement in another. If you watch Fringe, they address this well, where the alternate universe is more advanced in communications and medical technology, but far less advanced in transportation technology, such that they still use blimps.

Comment: @Gaius: To advance what fredsbend and Deion said, we even have cases of this happening in our own society. The most commonly cited example is that Meso-America knew of the wheel, but failed to use it for anything but pottery and toys. There is also the case of "Aryan physics," where the Nazis deliberately avoided the areas of physics discovered by Jews. Since Einstein was Jewish, this set back their knowledge of physics by several decades, making their quest for atomic weaponry that much harder. Likewise, several cultures ban autopsies, limiting medical advancement.

Comment: @SeanDuggan: Darth Vader was a prime contender for the position of the Sith'ari (http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith'ari) until he got himself chopped in half. Cybernetic enhancements have been established as limiting one's ability to interact with the Force; possibly for the simple reason that said enhancements aren't organic, and therefore can't contain (ugh) midi-chlorians.

Answer (score 34):

There is a lot of detail about Vader's amor in the [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Vader's_armor).

It includes the following about the vision:

> The eye lens acted as optical filters, allowing for Vader to expand the limits of human vision by detecting infrared and ultraviolet wavelengths, while also blocking out excess light, due to the inability to repair Vader's damaged retinas. In addition, the lens also came equipped with a HUD that supplied critical data automatically as an overlay if Vader entered new environments, including information about atmospheric composition, nearby bio-signatures, and others, which could also be selected via the mouth controls. The lens, likewise, came equipped with secondary eyeshields that activate within 5 milliseconds and automatically sliding over the optical blisters to prevent blindness when approaching intense light.

[image: helmet]

Comment: Man this really begs the question... if he can detect infrared how come he couldn't see Luke hiding under the broken bridge on the Deathstar 2.0 in Return of the Jedi?!

Comment: @Jared, see him? why would he need to see Luke to spot him when he can sense him with the Force? Why didn't he sense Luke either? Maybe Luke can hide his heat and Force signature using the Force as well...

Comment: @Deion: The ability to hide oneself using the Force is an ability practiced by Luke in the *EU*. Palpatine also practices it before he proclaims himself Emperor, but by far the greatest practitioner of the art is Vergere, who is able to disguise her Force presence from Jedi Grand Master Luke Skywalker despite sitting directly in front of him. So you might have that right.

Comment: "Maybe Luke can hide his heat and Force signature using the Force as well..." And here we have the essential problem with trying to reason about magic.

Comment: @Deion - he didn't need to sense him he already knew he was there, hence the taunts etc.

Answer (score 29):

The Lucasfilm licensed sourcebook "[Darth Vader : A 3-D Reconstruction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0545312159)" contains a wealth of detail about Darth's suit, transformation and an entire section about his visual capacity.

As you can see from the image below, his retinas were permanently injured. The suit augments his vision while protecting his eyes from excessive light and expanding his ability to view ultra-violet and infra-red wavelengths. There is also a mocked-up version to show how he views the Emperor.

[image]

This ties in very nicely with the in-helmet view of his vision that we get at the end of Episode III.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In a role-playing game for starwars, there was an entire force-sensitive race that was blind, but the only thing they could use the force for is see. Darth Vader could do that.